# replace URL into HTML Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used static http:// url into my html(s) page, now i want to replace with empty string.

Suppose here is HTML Content:

```
<div id="MSO_ContentTable">
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    function RedirectURL(RedUrl,curTab)
    {
       window.location.href='http://www.contoso.com/Sales/SitePages/'+RedUrl;
    }
    function nav2Lib(RedUrl)
    {
        NavigateHttpFolder('http://www.contoso.com/Sales/RFP%20Bank/'+h3url, '_blank');
    }
   function nav2Proposal(RedUrl)
   {
     NavigateHttpFolder('http://www.contoso.com/Sales/Proposals/'+h3url, '_blank');
   }
    </script>
  ........ lots of html contents
 </div>
```

### Edit :

```
   $('#MSO_ContentTable').html().replace(/http://www.contoso.com/g,'');
```

I want to replace whole url "http://www.contoso.com/" to empty string.

Comment: Have you considered to read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) about RegExp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think you need to `escape two forward slashes` that's it.

```
$('#MSO_ContentTable').html().replace(/http:\/\/www.contoso.com/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

The replace doesn't really need to use a regex, in your case (it's a simple replacement).

Also, in your code, you *get* the html from the table, perform an action on it, but then never set the resultant string back as the html of the table.

Try this:

```
$('#MSO_ContentTable').find([href^="http://www.contoso.com"]).each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href.replace('http://www.contoso.com', '');
});
```

It finds all children of the table with an href starting with http://www.contoso.com` and then replaces each href with empty string.

Comment: Sorry to say, I think you are mis-understading of my requirement. I have update question. please have a look

Comment: Thanks for your update, but it does not work for `NavigateHttpFolder('http://www.contoso.com/')` like this content.

Comment: Notice that the `find` I'm using is regex-like: the `^=`  means any href that *starts with* `http://www.contoso.com`

Answer (score 1):

Slashes in regular expressions need to be escaped: `/http:\/\/www.contoso.com/g`.  Alternately the replace method can take a string instead of a regular expression:

```
 var txt =  $('#MSO_ContentTable').html().replace('www.contoso.com','');
```

It's worth noting however that using a string here is technically different.  It looks like in this case there is only ever going to be one replacement but if you actually want to replace every instance of the patter (as the `g` flag would indicate) a string will not work.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags

Comment: Thank you, i got idea from `/http:\/\/www.contoso.com/g`. and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working,

You can check on fiddle.

```
var txt = $('#MSO_ContentTable').html();
alert(txt.replace(/www.contoso.com/g,''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mUMwd/